# How to show that the quotient group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R,+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let 
$$G=
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b \\
0 & a^{-1}
\end{bmatrix} \colon 
a,b\in \mathbb R; a>0
\end{Bmatrix} 
\mbox{ and } 
N=
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & b 
\\ 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\colon b\in \mathbb{R}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Prove that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R,+)$ and $G/N$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R^{+},*)$.

I have to get a onto homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb R$ whose kernel is $N$ .I am failing to do so.

Any hint would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: try with $$
\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b \\
0 & a^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto 
a
$$
as an homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: but why is the group isomorphic to $(\mathbb R,+)$

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^+$ via the exponential function

Comment: Yes you are right ;thank you very much+1

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the natural map: $G\rightarrow G$, given by 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b \\
0 & a^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a & 0 
\\ 0 & a^{-1} 
\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Is it a homomorphism? What is kernel and image?

Comment: Not sure really what are you talking about?

Comment: sorry; small mistake was done here.